# Oracle nvl function not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, null, nvl

I want to convert null values to `' '`. But when I use this code I got null values as 'NULL':

```
SELECT NVL(column_a, ' ') FROM table_a
```

Comment: empty string is not the same as  a space. empty string is the same as null, so what do you want?

Comment: column_a data type?

Comment: Are you sure your table column doesn't actually contain the string literal `'NULL'`, rather than really being null? What do you see if select `lower(column_a)` or `column_a||'test'`, or perhaps most definitively `dump(column_a)` ?

Comment: What IDE are you using? For instance SQL Developer displays null as `(null)`. Perhaps your client is doing something similar?

Comment: The function works just fine so you have two possible choices.  You actually have the value 'NULL' in the field or your IDE is removing white space.  I use Toad and it shows a single space character when viewed in hex.

Comment: I mean space already @hotfix

Comment: column_a data type is varchar @jarlh

Comment: I use Toad, I have value 'NULL' as a string, thank you all.

Comment: Then why have you accepted an answer that said something completely different?

Comment: No, it says GUI (Toad) displays NULL values as a string 'NULL'. Also your answer is a comment. If you put your answer as "answer", I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your GUI displays "NULL" for those values, it is the GUI setting, not Oracle value. Set it to something else (e.g. *nothing*, in your case).

Comment: Why would any GUI report a single space as `NULL`? (Wondering if the question might have changed significantly in the grace period as you answered within that? And hotfix's comment might also suggest that happened...)

Comment: @AlexPoole - I thing hotfix's comment may be a red herring. The SO UI renders ' ' very close together, so it quite looks like an empty string. I applied markdown to verify that the OP does want to default null to a space.

Comment: @APC - that was how I first interpreted the comment, but as the code block clearly has a space, and this answer doesn't make sense for a space either (as the code can't return null - unless I'm missing something!?), I wondered if the OP originally did have `''` in the code then fixed it. <shrug>

Comment: It was space. In spite of the other character 'xxx', it didn't work. Problem is releated  with 'NULL' value as a string.